# Illegal Instruction - Kernel Modules

Tags: module, linux-kernel, arm, arm64, illegal-instruction

I'm trying to follow these instructions:

https://developer.arm.com/products/system-design/cycle-models/knowledge-articles/system-performance-analysis-and-the-arm-performance-monitor-unit

My goal here is to enable userspace access for the PMUs. These are some of the instructions of the module I'm using.

```
static void enable_cpu_counters(void* data)                                                                         
{                                                                                                       
    asm volatile("msr pmuserenr_el0, %0" :: "r"(0xf));
    armv8pmu_pmcr_write (ARMV8_PMCR_LC|ARMV8_PMCR_E);                                                      
    asm volatile("msr PMCNTENSET_EL0, %0" :: "r" ((u32)(1<<31)));
    armv8pmu_pmcr_write(armv8pmu_pmcr_read() | ARMV8_PMCR_E|ARMV8_PMCR_LC);   
    printk("\nCPU:%d \n", smp_processor_id());
}                                                                                                       

static void disable_cpu_counters (void* data)                                                                        
{                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    printk(KERN_INFO "\ndisabling user-mode PMU access on CPU #%d \n",                       
    smp_processor_id());
    /* Program PMU and disable all counters */                                                            
    armv8pmu_pmcr_write(armv8pmu_pmcr_read() |~ARMV8_PMCR_E);                                              
    asm volatile("msr pmuserenr_el0, %0" ::"r"((u64)0));                                                 
}                                                                                                       

static int __init init(void)                                                                                              
{
    unsigned int reguser=0;     

    isb();

    asm volatile("mrs %0, pmcr_el0" : "=r" (reguser));
    printk(KERN_INFO "\nPMCR_EL0 register before : %x\n", reguser);
    asm volatile("mrs %0, pmuserenr_el0" : "=r" (reguser));
    printk(KERN_INFO "\nPMUSERENR register before : %x\n", reguser);

on_each_cpu (enable_cpu_counters, NULL, 1);                                                             
    printk(KERN_INFO "\nEnable Access PMU Initialized\n");

    /* Enable counters */
    asm volatile("mrs %0, pmcr_el0" : "=r" (reguser));
    printk(KERN_INFO "\nPMCR_EL0 register after : %x\n", reguser);
    asm volatile("mrs %0, pmuserenr_el0" : "=r" (reguser));
    printk(KERN_INFO "\nPMUSERENR register after : %x\n", reguser);

    return 0;                                                                                              
}                                                                                                       

static void __exit fini(void)                                                                                              
{                                                                                                       
    on_each_cpu(disable_cpu_counters, NULL, 1);                                                            
    printk(KERN_INFO "\nAccess PMU Disabled\n");                                                          
}                                                                                                       

module_init (init);                                                                                      
module_exit (fini);
```

**Output (dmesg):**

```
[79371.445026] \x0aPMCR_EL0 register before : 41023040
[79371.450997] \x0aPMUSERENR register before : 0
[79371.456511] \x0aCPU:3
[79371.456546] \x0aCPU:2
[79371.456614] \x0aCPU:0
[79371.456631] \x0aCPU:4
[79371.456652] \x0aCPU:5
[79371.473784] \x0aCPU:1
[79371.477254] \x0aEnable Access PMU Initialized
[79371.482693] \x0aPMCR_EL0 register after : 41023001
[79371.488560] \x0aPMUSERENR register after : f
```

---

Followed with a second module, this time only reading the values from the registers.

**Module (testing if it keeps the values on the registers):**

```
static int __init init(void)                                                                                              
{        
    unsigned int reguser=0;                                                               
    isb();

    /* Enable counters */
    asm volatile("mrs %0, pmcr_el0" : "=r" (reguser));
    printk(KERN_INFO "\nPMCR_EL0 register : %x\n", reguser);
    asm volatile("mrs %0, pmuserenr_el0" : "=r" (reguser));
    printk(KERN_INFO "\nPMUSERENR register : %x\n", reguser);

    return 0;                                                                                              
}                                                                                                       

static void __exit fini(void)                                                                                              
{                                                                                                                                                         
    printk(KERN_INFO "\nDisabling read_arm_pmu.ko\n");                                                          
}                                                                                                       

module_init (init);                                                                                      
module_exit (fini);
```

**Output (dmesg):**

```
[79385.429198] \x0aPMCR_EL0 register : 41023040
[79385.434584] \x0aPMUSERENR register : 0
```

---

Testing the functionality on userspace with a simple program gives:

```
juno:/data/data/papi/workplace # ./monitoring 2 2 2 3
[1359092.706711] monitoring[11095]: undefined instruction: pc=000000000040065c
[1359092.713652] Code: 00000000 00000000 00000000 d10043ff (d53b9c00)
Illegal instruction
```

**NOTE:** I know it is probably because PMCR_EL0's first bit is 0 and PMUSERENR not being f. Don't know how to make it so that the module doesn't change back the values from the registers...

---

**Useful commands that may help debug:**

**juno:/ # cat /proc/modules**

read_arm_pmu 16384 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000 (PO)

enable_arm_pmu 16384 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000 (PO)

**juno:/ # cat /proc/devices**

Character devices:
1 mem
5 /dev/tty
5 /dev/console
5 /dev/ptmx
10 misc
13 input
14 sound
29 fb
90 mtd
108 ppp
116 alsa
128 ptm
136 pts
180 usb
189 usb_device
204 ttyAMA
226 drm
249 roccat
250 hidraw
251 bsg
252 tee
253 rtc
254 gpiochip

Block devices:
1 ramdisk
259 blkext
7 loop
8 sd
31 mtdblock
65 sd
66 sd
67 sd
68 sd
69 sd
70 sd
71 sd
128 sd
129 sd
130 sd
131 sd
132 sd
133 sd
134 sd
135 sd
179 mmc
253 device-mapper
254 virtblk

**cat /proc/sys/kernel/tainted**

4097

**juno:/ # cat /proc/interrupts**

CPU0 CPU1 CPU2 CPU3 CPU4 CPU5

2: 1844410 1197983 1353732 16779 3199 5419 GIC v2 92 Level arch_mem_timer

3: 0 0 0 0 0 0 GIC v2 29 Level arch_timer

4: 894927 272142 288023 18616 39333 15390 GIC v2 30 Level arch_timer

7: 0 0 0 0 0 0 GIC v2 198 Level timer

14: 419017 0 0 0 0 0 GIC v2 68 Level mhu_link

15: 0 0 0 0 0 0 GIC v2 67 Level mhu_link

16: 0 0 0 0 0 0 GIC v2 120 Level 7ff00000.dma

17: 0 0 0 0 0 0 GIC v2 121 Level 7ff00000.dma

18: 0 0 0 0 0 0 GIC v2 122 Level 7ff00000.dma

19: 0 0 0 0 0 0 GIC v2 123 Level 7ff00000.dma

20: 0 0 0 0 0 0 GIC v2 124 Level 7ff00000.dma

21: 0 0 0 0 0 0 GIC v2 140 Level 7ff00000.dma

22: 0 0 0 0 0 0 GIC v2 141 Level 7ff00000.dma

23: 0 0 0 0 0 0 GIC v2 142 Level 7ff00000.dma

24: 0 0 0 0 0 0 GIC v2 143 Level 7ff00000.dma

25: 0 0 0 0 0 0 GIC v2 125 Level hdlcd

26: 0 0 0 0 0 0 GIC v2 117 Level hdlcd

27: 6336 0 0 0 0 0 GIC v2 115 Level uart-pl011

28: 53666 0 0 0 0 0 GIC v2 136 Level 7ffa0000.i2c

30: 47345 0 0 0 0 0 GIC v2 149 Level ehci_hcd:usb1

33: 14370 0 0 0 0 0 GIC v2 65 Level 2d000000.gpu

34: 0 0 0 0 0 0 GIC v2 66 Level 2d000000.gpu

35: 39222 0 0 0 0 0 GIC v2 64 Level 2d000000.gpu

37: 52 0 0 0 0 0 GIC v2 194 Level mmci-pl18x (cmd)

40: 0 0 0 0 0 0 GIC v2 100 Level rtc-pl031

43: 0 0 0 0 0 0 GIC v2 169 Level sata_sil24[0000:03:00.0]

45: 0 0 0 0 0 0 M SI 0 Edge PCIe PME, aerdrv

52: 1049234 0 0 0 0 0 M SI 4194304 Edge eth0

IPI0: 62569 1835646 1888285 43688 29194 29798 R escheduling interrupts

IPI1: 315 1276 725 386 307 207 F unction call interrupts

IPI2: 0 0 0 0 0 0 C PU stop interrupts

IPI3: 829962 24938 62500 1274 498 1029 T imer broadcast interrupts

IPI4: 800250 925302 1266671 10821 9264 7192 I RQ work interrupts

IPI5: 0 0 0 0 0 0 C PU wake-up interrupts

Err: 0

I hope you guys can help me, it feels i'm wasting a lot of time in something that may be simple.

**TLDR** - The kernel module should enable userspace access and it isn't working. Looking for help to know why.

Thanks,
Luis

---

**EDIT:** Formating, making my problem clearer.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I've successfully used the kernel module trick on older devboards, but on a new one I'm running into the exact same issue.

It was suggested in https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/955554/jetson-tx1/performance-counters-reset-itself/ that disabling `CONFIG_CPU_IDLE` could help, and it does help for me. With that disabled, I'm able to set bits in `pmuserenr_el0` via a kernel module, and enable/use the counter via userspace.

However, I've successfully used the kernel module on a Dragonboard 410c running the Debian 83 image for it, which runs [debian-qcom-dragonboard410c-16.04](https://git.linaro.org/landing-teams/working/qualcomm/kernel.git/tag/?h=debian-qcom-dragonboard410c-16.04) kernel. That particular kernel also has got `CONFIG_CPU_IDLE` enabled, so apparently something has changed at some point, making `CONFIG_CPU_IDLE` break the PMU access.

Out of curiosity, I also tested adjusting the [`reset_pmuserenr_el0`](https://github.com/friendlyarm/kernel-rockchip/blob/3d5962249d52f8f5454cf9fab288a507cc3d3d07/arch/arm64/include/asm/assembler.h#L331) macro to set `pmuserenr_el0` to `0xf` instead of clearing it, to see if I could keep `CONFIG_CPU_IDLE` enabled. That does allow me to access the PMU registers from userspace, but any benchmarking is impossible as the counters end up stopped all the time.

Unfortunately, disabling `CONFIG_CPU_IDLE` requires you to rebuild the kernel - it's not enough to just load a new module.